# find the indices of top n elements in an Array in Scala

Tags: scala

I have an unordered Array[Int]. How can I find the indices of the top n elements from it?

For example

```
Input:
Array[Int] = Array(1,4,2,8,5,3,1,4,2)
top_n = 3

Output:
1,4,5
```

Comment: how you determine top n? whats the logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm supposing you are asking for the indices of the 3 highest numbers?
You could use something like this:

```
arr.zipWithIndex.sortBy(_._1).takeRight(3).map(_._2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the output you've described is wrong, so I suppose here it should be (1,3,4). Here is a sraightforward solution using zipWithIndex

```
val values = Array(1,4,2,8,5,3,1,4,2)
val n = 3
values.zipWithIndex.sortBy(-_._1).take(n).map(_._2)
```

Which returns

```
res2: Array[Int] = Array(3, 4, 1)
```